# HID communication between Raspberry Pi and HTC Vive Tracker

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb, raspbian, hid, htc-vive

I am trying to use a raspberry pi to send feature reports to a Vive tracker. However I've come across a bit of a problem when I connect both of them.

Whenever I boot up the pi with the vive connected the vive stops being tracked on SteamVR. However when I reboot the pi it tracks again despite the fact that the vive is connected via bluetooth to a pc running unity.

I've set up udev rules for the vive tracker and checked the output of /dev/hidraw0 which is empty on reboot but on boot constantly outputs, does that mean the pi is using the tracker? If so how can I find out what?

Is there a way to stop the pi from using the interfaces which I need to run my script and allow the tracker to track on SteamVR while plugged into the pi without having to reboot each time?

I've tried killing any process using the interface (through fuser) and printing logs of boot up processes and reboot processes but haven't found anything that would cause this

Comment: When hidraw outputs data, it means the vive is synced & connected with your raspberry pi and properly sending frames to it.  I've written joystick apps that create virtual HID devices before the actual joysticks are activated. That way, my virtual devices take up the first few joystick slots; I then program UDEV to kill off the actual joysticks so that game systems can not open them.  This allows me to intercept and reprogram the joystick devices to act as other kinds of controllers.  The same principle can be used for what you want, and to debug it; But, bounty time is too short.